# How to call this.function from inside another function within Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

When I try to call a function from within a timeout function I get `Uncaught TypeError: this.checkMounted is not a function` The function runs fine when it's not within the timeout.

How do I correctly access this.function

```
methods: {
  checkMounted: function () {    
},
mounted() {
  setTimeout(function(){ 
     this.checkMounted()
  }, 3000); 
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1)** This is the problem of `this` binding. You can use the `arrow` function to solve this problem. [CODESANDBOX](https://codesandbox.io/s/sleepy-nova-mxomu?file=/src/App.vue:147-302)

Pass `arrow` function instead of `normal` function in `setTimeout`

```
setTimeout(() => {
      this.logValues();
    }, 2000);
```

instead of

```
setTimeout(function(){
      this.logValues();
    }, 2000);
```

When you use a normal function then `this` binding is dependent on how the function is called. Here `this` will be `Window` object and there is no method named `checkMounted` on the `window` object and produces an error.

You can read more about [this on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work)

---

**2)** There is one more way that you could solve this problem, This is an old-school method and was used before ES6 arrow function. [CODESANDBOX](https://codesandbox.io/s/adoring-christian-xfjdi?file=/src/App.vue)

```
  mounted() {
    const that = this;
    setTimeout(function () {
      that.logValues();
    }, 2000);
  },
```

Comment: Thank you, I'll read more about `this`. It looks pretty dense, but to recap, I'm not accessing the global function called checkMounted. The arrow syntax access this in a global scope.

Comment: `global` object in the browser is `window` object. When you use normal function then you get the reference of `window` of `this`. But what you need is that `this` should refer `vue` instance not `window.`